Type inference failed. The value of the type parameter T should be mentioned in input types in when block
I get this error in android studio "Type inference failed. The value of the type parameter T should be mentioned in input types (argument types, receiver type or expected type). Try to specify it explicitly. :349 , :350 "
It's nearly 2 days that i can't fix it
And here is my code snippet 346:353
private fun scoreOfRate(rate: Double): Double {
    return when {
        rate <= 100 -> (rate / 100) * 50
        rate in 101..120 -> 100.0
        rate in 121..160 -> 100 - (mapValue((rate - 120).toFloat(), 1.toFloat(), 160.toFloat(), 0.toFloat(), 100.toFloat()).toDouble()) * 1.0
        else -> 0.0
        }
    }

fun mapValue(value: Float, fromLow: Float, fromHigh: Float, toLow: Float, toHigh: Float): Float {
        return (value - fromLow) / (fromHigh - fromLow) * (toHigh - toLow) + toLow
    }

(It's in kotlin)
I asked about it from copilot gemini chatgpt but non of them could solve it.
I used every technique from other posts

where exactly is the problem? should show-up in logcat

it's in the problem section of android studio

You check for rate in 101..120, and then 121..160. What if rate is 120.5?

This is working , mentioned the data type in the input params like this rate in (121f..160f)
private fun scoreOfRate(rate: Double): Double {

return when {
    rate <= 100 -> {
        (rate / 100) * 50
    }
    rate in (101f..121f) -> {
        100.0
    }

    rate in 121f..160f -> {
        100 - (mapValue((rate - 120).toFloat(), 1.toFloat(), 160.toFloat(), 0.toFloat(), 100.toFloat()).toDouble()) * 1.0
    }
    else -> {
        0.0
    }
}
} 


thx very much it worked :)
